# Can an colon and an em dash be used in the same sentence?

Tags: punctuation

Or is it considered poor punctuation?
For instance, I read this recently:

The school nurse had seen what Aunt Petunia's eyes–– so sharp when it came to spotting fingerprints on her gleaming walls, and in observing the comings and goings of the neighbors--simply refused to see: that, far from needing extra nourishment, Dudley had reached roughly the size and weight of a young killer whale.

–– J.K. Rowling, Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire

Comment: Are there _two_ em-dashes? If so, can you please replicate them properly. // It would probably be 'not recommended' in style guides, but the lady usually pulls off controversial effects marvellously well. _I like it here_, think it works superbly, and, if it is accurately reproduced, will use it as a licensing example.

Comment: ... They're en-dashes in my copy. Perhaps an odd font, but definitely white-spaced. They're commonly used in the UK where em-dashes would be expected in the US.